# Installed librairies can't be imported in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've created a python 3.6 environment using the conda command. I have then activated that environment and installed a few librairies.
I then open a Jupyter Notebook in this environment using Anaconda Navigator and I am unable of importing graphviz, a librairie I have installed.

The name of the kernel on the top right is Python 3 and not the name of my environment.

How can I install librairies in my environment and then import them in Jupyter Notebook?

Thank you for any help

*Code I ran to create my environment and install the librairies:*

```
conda create -n myEnv pip python=3.6

activate myEnv

conda install -c conda-forge opencv

conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

Comment: This problem has yet to be resolved.
If anyone knows how to fix it, let me know